# How to delete a repetead value in a multimap c++?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

I have a multimap filled with these elements (key, value):

PROJECTONE,asdsa

PROJECTTWO,asdsa

PROJECTTHREE,hello

PROJECTFOUR,asdsa

I want to delete all the elements of the multimap with the same value, it doesn´t matter if the key is different as you see in the example. In this example, i need to delete projectone, projecttwo and projectfour because they have the same value (asdsa).. so the output when i print the multimap is only:

PROJECTTHREE,hello

Comment: Maps are not optimized for value-based operations. Since you will have O(n) complexity in any case, the most straightforward approach is to iterate over the map and remove items with this value. I'm not sure, but `remove_if` may also work: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/remove_if/

Comment: Hi Raul! We would need an code example to go from. When in doubt check https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @dyukha remove_if doesn't work with (unordered) associative containers, because it mutates the elements

Answer (score 0):

A iterative approach like this can solve your problem.

```
std::unordered_set<string> s; // to track the values seen so far.
for (auto it = m.cbegin(); it != m.cend() /* not hoisted */; /* no increment */)
{

  if (s.find(it->second) != s.end())
  {
    m.erase(it++);    // or "it = m.erase(it)" since C++11
  }
  else
  {
    s.emplace(it->second);
    ++it;
  }
}
```